# What's the difference between the library and applicationSupport directories?

Tags: swift4, xcode9.2

xcode 9.2 ; swift 4

I want to persist some data for my ios app in the form of property lists. I don't want to use the Documents directory of the sandbox, since the user can manipulate it. I have two alternatives: the library directory and the applicationSupport directory. Is there an advantage in using one or the other?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have two alternatives: the library directory and the applicationSupport directory. Is there an advantage in using one or the other?

Yes, Apple recommend you use *Application Support*.

Though a sandboxed app has its own private little file system hierarchy you are still expected to follow the guidelines as though the sandbox was not there.

Just remember, wherever you store the data the "user can manipulate it", hiding it in the sandbox is no deterrent to that.

HTH